# PHP Creating JSON array list (data coming from MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, database

I am a novice in Json and I am not able to fill json list with data gathered from mysql query.
Only one value is filled in the list and it keeps repeating rather than showing all the values.
The code is:

```
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db('abcd');
$jsonData = 0;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT picname,title,date,time,location,timestamp FROM uploaded_photo_data ORDER BY timestamp DESC ");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $a = $row['location']."/".$row['picname']; 
        echo $row['timestamp'];
        echo $a;
        echo $row['picname'];
        echo $row['title'];
        echo $row['location'];
        echo "<br></br>";

        $dir = $row['location']."/"; 
        $jsonData = '{';     
        $x = 0;
        $dirHandle = opendir($dir);
        while($x!=$num){
            $x++;
            $jsonData .= '"img'.$x.'":{ "num":"'.$x.'","title":"'.$row['title'].'","src":"'.$a.'", "timestamp":"'.$row['timestamp'].'"},<br></br> ';
        }

    }
}
closedir($dirHandle);
        $jsonData = chop($jsonData, ",");
        $jsonData .= '}'; 
        echo $jsonData; echo $x;
```

Comment: This code has no logic. You create `$jsonData` variable inside first while loop, then in the same loop (still dealing with first row) you iterate the number of rows times and fill the `$jsonData`. Then again and again, while `$jsonData` are always overwritten. Your `$jsonData` will in the end contain last database result row n times, where n is number of results. My advice, start from scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can encode an array to JSON with the `json_encode` method.

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

EDIT:

Maybe this works for you:

```
$jsonData = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $a = $row['location']."/".$row['picname']; 
    echo $row['timestamp'];
    echo $a;
    echo $row['picname'];
    echo $row['title'];
    echo $row['location'];
    echo "<br></br>";

    $dir = $row['location']."/";    
    $x = 0;

    while($x!=$num){
        $x++;
        $img = 'img'.$x;
        $jsonData[$img] = array(
            "num" => $x,
            "title" => $row['title'],
            "src" => $a,
            "timestamp" => $row['timestamp']
        );
    }
}

print json_encode($jsonData);
```

Comment: perfect answer. But it will be better if you solve this issue by using code form questions.